# Representation of inner source-retained annotation

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

We have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    private @interface MyInterface { }

    @MyInterface
    public void hello() { }
}
```

As you can see, it has an inner, source-only annotation. My question is: should the exported binary (jar) contain the `MyClass$MyInterface.class` file or not? If we look at the retention, we can say not, because this annotation should be discarded by the compiler. However it is still added to the list of inner classes in `MyClass.class`, and the `MyClass$MyInterface.class` file is also created.

When we run an an annotation processor against this class

```
public class MyProcessedClass extends MyClass {}
```

the annotation processing fails if we [call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getEnclosedElements%28%29)

```
myClass.getEnclosedElements()
```

and `MyClass$MyInterface.class` is not present. The processing is OK, if `MyClass$MyInterface.class` is present.

([original problem](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1435#issuecomment-106765841))

Comment: In `myClass.getEnclosedElements()`, what is `myClass`? A `TypeElement` representing `MyClass` or `MyProcessedClass`?

Comment: That supposed to be MyClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: should the exported binary (jar) contain the `MyClass$MyInterface.class` file or not?

It should.

[*13.1. The Form of a Binary*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1):

> 10. Every class must contain symbolic references to all of its member types, and to all local and anonymous classes that appear in its methods, constructors, static initializers, instance initializers, and field initializers.

[*4.7.6. The `InnerClasses` Attribute*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.6):

> If a class or interface has members that are classes or interfaces, its `constant_pool` table (and hence its `InnerClasses` attribute) must refer to each such member, even if that member is not otherwise mentioned by the class.

So `MyClass` must have a reference to `MyInterface`. And although I don't have a citation for this, it would seem that if there are references to a particular class, then that class should be compiled.

Comment: Thanks! I also checked both JLS and JVM spec, but i think i searched for wrong terms.